# How to use button.click in gridview row bound event

Tags: asp.net

Gridview has auto-generated column.I wanted to select the perticular row,so added one button in gridview.In rowbound event,i want like if(btnshow.click){//color code for that row}.Does it right way.Button is not visible in this event(when I am making if condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `RowCommand` event. Row index is then `e.CommandArgument`. Read this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand.aspx) help for how to do this.

***Edit:*** answer to your comment -- by using the BackColor property:

```
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

  GridViewRow row = gridView1.Rows[index];

  row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: Ya,I came to know upto this much that when button is used in gridview,used Rowcommand event,Commandname and command argument.How to make entire row in color when that row's button is clicked.